# Unique Random Integer within a For Loop

Tags: php, arrays, random

I'm trying to access 4 random entries in a nested array. So far I've come up with this code:

```
$section = array_rand($acc);  // Create random array
$index = count($acc);         // Array Size
echo '<div><ul>';
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {  // fetch 4 elements of array randomly
    $index = rand ( 0 , $index ); // generate random index
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a>'.$acc[$index]['title'].'</a>';
    echo '<span>';
    echo $acc[$index]['content'];
    echo '</span>';
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul></div>';
```

The problem, of course, is that as every time the loop goes through it generates a random number but there is no guarantee that it won't be the same number in the previous iteration of the loop.

Is there another way to go about this?

The objective is to get 4 unique random arrays nested in a randomly selected array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will pick up to 4 random keys and then use them. If you have less than 4 keys then it'll select all of them.

```
$keys = array_rand($acc, min(4, sizeof($acc)));

echo '<div><ul>';
foreach($keys as $key) {
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a>'.$acc[$key]['title'].'</a>';
    echo '<span>';
    echo $acc[$key]['content'];
    echo '</span>';
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul></div>';
```

Comment: Thanks, I added some missing brackets and parentheses:

`$keys = array_rand($acc, min(4, sizeof($acc)));

echo '<div><ul>';
foreach($keys as $key){
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a>'.$acc[$key]['title'].'</a>';
    echo '<span>';
    echo $acc[$key]['content'];
    echo '</span>';
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul></div>';`

Comment: Is there any way to access re-select the parent array before selecting the content from the nested array?

Comment: I don't follow what you mean? The main array is `$acc`? It's always accessible.

Comment: Basically I need to access a random (but not unique) parent array and a unique random nested array in each iteration of the loop.

I asked this question in the WordPress forum: 
[link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/259422/4-unique-random-posts-based-on-custom-field-values) which explains what I'm really trying to do.

Comment: I posted a comment on your other post.

Answer (score 0):

You need an array or an object to keep track uniqueness. When number matches in the array (you've previously used that number), then skip the logic and loop through again with another random number.

Answer (score 0):

One rudimentary solution is to keep a list of the previously generated random integers and generate a new random integer anytime it collides. For example:

1. Draw a 1, not in list {}, use it
2. Draw a 2, not in list {1}, use it
3. Draw another 1, is in list {1,2}, don't use it, draw again
4. Draw a 3, not in list {1,2,3}

Another solution, useful if you need the whole list shuffled, is to make a copy of your list, then pick and remove an element at random and add it to a shuffled list. Do this over and over again until the copy is empty. This is the "52 Card Pickup" method of shuffling.

I'm sure some time on google would provide a more formal exploration of this topic with perhaps better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do something like this:

```
<?php
$numIndexes = count($acc);
$usedIndexes = array();

echo '<ul>';

for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) { 

    do{
        $index = rand ( 0 , $numIndexes ); 
    }
    while(!in_array($index, $usedIndexes));

    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a>'.$acc[$index]['title'].'</a>';
    echo '<div>';
    echo $acc[$index]['content'];
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</li>';

    $usedIndexes[] = $index;
}

echo '</ul>';
echo '</div>';
```

This is not tested, but it should work...